# Android Kotlin Retrofit Extract a single information from response.body()

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Using Retrofit, I just Call a GET Request from an endpoint successfully. It returns the proper response in the `response.body()`. In the Logcat, it is like [this][1].

The response look like this in postman:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Now what i want to extract from `response.body` is that `Header` attribute and pass them to some textviews. As you can see above, it is a single object.

All examples in the internet of how to use retrofit is using it to populate a recyclerview. As for this, it is a single object and i want to show them not in a listview or a recyclerview.

Here's the snippet code of the layout where i want to show them (It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h7GV.jpg)):

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="24dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailOutletName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="XXX"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailOrderNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="XXX"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailOrderDateTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="XXX"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dtailOrderTotalPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="XXX"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailCustomerName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="XXX"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailCustomerAddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="XXX"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
                
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailCustomerPhone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="XXX"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the data class I use:

```
data class OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClass(

    @field:SerializedName("data")
    val data: OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("error")
    val error: Error? = null
)

data class OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassData(

    @field:SerializedName("Header")
    val header: OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassHeader? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("Detail")
    val detail: List<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassDetailItem?>? = null
)

data class OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassHeader(

    @field:SerializedName("buyer_address")
    val buyerAddress: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("total_price")
    val totalPrice: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("buyer_name")
    val buyerName: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status_confirmed_yn")
    val statusConfirmedYn: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_date")
    val orderDate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("outlet_id")
    val outletId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("nip")
    val nip: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("jumlah_product")
    val jumlahProduct: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("last_update")
    val lastUpdate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("phone_number")
    val phoneNumber: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_running_id")
    val orderRunningId: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status_tagged_yn")
    val statusTaggedYn: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_id")
    val orderId: String? = null
)
```

Here's the code snippet from the fragment of the layout:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val args = arguments?.let { OrderDetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it) }
        val selectedOrderId = args?.orderId

        // Change action bar title
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Order Details"


        // View Binding for this Fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_order_detail, container, false
        )

        if (selectedOrderId != null) {
            fetchOrderDetail(selectedOrderId)
            fetchOrderedItemListData(selectedOrderId)
        }


        //Inflate layout to this activity fragment
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun fetchOrderDetail(selectedOrderId : String){
        NetworkConfig()
            .getOutstandingDetailService()
            .getOutstandingOrderDetail(selectedOrderId)
            .enqueue(object :
                Callback<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClass>{
                override fun onFailure(
                    call: Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClass>,
                    t: Throwable
                ) {
                    ....
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClass>,
                    response: Response<OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClass>
                ) {
                    Log.i("Order", "Order Detail fetched! -> \n ${response.body()}") //This line is how the response.body() shown in the logcat.
                }
            })
    }
```

Is there a way to do achieve that ? If there's any detail that i miss to point out, feel free to ask.

Comment: inside the log please try like this `response.body().data?.header` and try

Comment: @satuser So what i need to do is just access each attribute with `response.body().data?.header.attributeName` ?

Comment: @satuser It's working! Many thanks dude. I suggest you write the answer so it'll help other user in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the `Header` part of the response, you need to access it like `response.body().data?.header` or do it like below

```
 val responseData = response.body().data

  //now you can get any values inside the data object as like below

val header = responseData?.header

val attributeName  = header?.attributeName
```

Answer (score 1):

The logs show you are getting an instance of `OutstandingOrderDetailPOJODataClassHeader` class in `response.body()` so you can access the data in `onResponse` as `response.body().data?.header.attributeName` and appropriately set that in the `TextViews`. Similarly `detail` can be accessed.